# Using page field value in a metatag in <head>

Tags: theming, 8

I would like to edit my `html.html.twig` template to assign a value to a metatag in `<head>` according to the value of a field of a page. Is that possible?

I was trying things like `{{ page.myfield.value }}`, but with no success and haven't found anything helpful online.

Comment: Is the field part of a node?

Comment: The field is a part of a page / content type that is being displayed, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Content types are nodes, so yeah, that answers my question. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the tag in hook_node_view() (which is derived from [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()](http://hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view(array%20&$build,%20%5CDrupal%5CCore%5CEntity%5CEntityInterface%20$entity,%20%5CDrupal%5CCore%5CEntity%5CDisplay%5CEntityViewDisplayInterface%20$display,%20$view_mode)), when the view mode is full (which makes the assumption that the full view mode is only ever used on node pages).

You can do that as follows:

```
function hook_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $mpde, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode)
{
  // Check if the view mode is full
  if($view_mode == 'full')
  {
    // Create the tag. You can set the content of the
    // metatag from the node
    $tag = [
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => [
        'name' => 'name attribute of metatag',
        // Note that 'value' will differ depending on the
        // field type.
        'content' => $node->get('field_something')->value,
      ],
    ];

    // Attach the meta tag to the header.
    $build['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$tag, 'some_key_to_represent_tag'];
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks good, thank you. Sorry for asking basic questions, but I have added to my mytheme.theme changed the 'name' appropriately, as well as the 'field_something', cleared the drupal caches, but still nothing. Is there any step I'm missing?

Comment: Still nothing :-( I have put the code with my adjustments here: https://codeshare.io/5vANrK. I'd be really grateful for any help fixing this.

Comment: You cannot use the function name hook_node_view(), you need to alter it for the module/theme in which it resides, according to Drupal hook naming conventions: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/understanding-the-hook-system-for-drupal-modules

Comment: yes, I renamed the function to mytheme_hook_node_view, where mytheme is the right name of my theme, but still no difference, the metatag does not appear in the code (of course, clearing caches)

Comment: It should be THEMENAME_node_view(). Remove 'hook'.

Comment: Silly mistake. I did that, but still nothing.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Time to do some debugging. Is your function even called?